# BrowserMobProxy: ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] after system restart

Tags: python-3.x, browsermob-proxy

I am using BrowserMobProxy to examine the traffic generated by my selenium webdriver. After restarting my PC I receive

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made
> because the target machine actively refused

message. It looks like it was not stopped correctly, by can it effect my system even after restart? Any advice?

Here is my code:

```
from browsermobproxy  import Server
from selenium import webdriver

class ProxyManager:
    browsermobproxy_path = "D:/browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy.bat"

    def __init__(self):
        self.server = Server(ProxyManager.browsermobproxy_path)
        self.client = None #will be initialized manually for better control

    def start_server(self):
        self.server.start()
        return self.server

    def start_client(self):
        #disable certificate check
        self.client = self.server.create_proxy(params={"trustALLServers":"true"})
        return self.client

if "__main__" == __name__:
    proxy = ProxyManager()
    server = proxy.start_server()
    client = proxy.start_client()
```

and here is my bmp.log:

```
[INFO  2020-09-04T01:02:13,322 net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.Main] (main) Starting BrowserMob Proxy version 2.1.4 
[INFO  2020-09-04T01:02:13,434 org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] (main) jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT 
[INFO  2020-09-04T01:02:13,710 org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] (main) started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null} 
[WARN  2020-09-04T01:02:14,170 org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] (main) FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind 
[WARN  2020-09-04T01:02:14,172 org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] (main) FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@56f0cc85: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind 
[ERROR 2020-09-04T01:02:14,218 net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.Main] (main) Failed to start Jetty server. Aborting. java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:162) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:356) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:240) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:269) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55) ~[browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
    at net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.Main.main(Main.java:64) [browsermob-dist-2.1.4.jar:?]
```

my full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 172, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000273DE63C5C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8866): Max retries exceeded with url: http://localhost:8080/proxy?trustALLServers=true (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000273DE63C5C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 23, in start_client
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\browsermobproxy\server.py", line 40, in create_proxy
    client = Client(self.url[7:], params)
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\browsermobproxy\client.py", line 31, in __init__
    resp = requests.post('%s/proxy' % self.host + urlparams)
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kosh\PycharmProjects\CSSSR_Selenium\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8866): Max retries exceeded with url: http://localhost:8080/proxy?trustALLServers=true (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000273DE63C5C8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had found that if the script will halt at some point without executing `server.stop()` it will mess with the system proxy settings by not clearing the changes it had made.